# Drone update status of each job on github

Tags: github, drone.io

I recently started using drone with my github repo.
One problem i have facing past week was I was not able to add job status of drone to github repo.

I am getting below status on my Github pr.

[image]
I want to replace those status and add status for each job.

What i have researched

Can add curl request to every fail/pass build to update status of each job or use existing plugins for same.
But i wanted to know whether we can replace above status to a custom one, if YES, then how?